# is it possible to have internal style sheet for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, error, style.css

Lets say I have a new form that
and I want to have a tag somewhere
like this:

```
<style>
#id{
  background:red;
}
</style>
```

at the moment when I do this my SharePoint gives me an error saying `Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.`

Comment: Do you have access to Script Editor or Content editor webpart in your site? You can add custom CSS on list form page using these webparts.

Comment: ahhh i see got it but is there away i can do it from sharepoint designer (the source code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find if there is a `<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server"></SharePoint:StyleBlock>`
in your new form.You could add css code in it.

**My test code:**

```
<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">   
nobr{    
color:red
}
</SharePoint:StyleBlock>
```

**Test result:**
[image]

Comment: yeah i just found it 
anyways thank you for the answer